# Sessão em Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, session

Eu estava lendo que o *middleware* [Express Session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) não é ideal para se trabalhar em produção, por que arquiva as sessões em memória. Li também que armazenar dados de sessão em memória não é uma boa prática.

Então, a minha pergunta é: qual a melhor forma de se usar sessões em Node.JS?

Comment: Use `express-session` em conjunto com algum dos vários módulos de armazenamento de sessão... eu recomendo `connect-mongo` mas, podes usar mysql, dynamo, couchbase, sqlite, redis, oracle, etc...

Comment: Armazenar os dados da sessão em uma base de dados torna a requisição um pouco mais lenta, não? Há um jeito de armazenar em disco, como o PHP faz?

Comment: Sim, memória é mais rápido. Podes usar um armazenamento em disco como [`session-file-store`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store) ... estes armazenamentos em "disco" não são recomendados para grandes aplicações, conforme o sistema cresce deve enfrentar problemas de concorrência no sistema de leitura e escrita. Bases de dados são projetadas para trabalhar sobre este aspecto permitindo "paralelização" das chamadas concorrentes, divisão de "pools", etc...

Comment: sessões, no geral, n são o ideal atualmente pq faz com que seu *server* não obedeça os princípios REST, especificamente em não serem *stateless*.

Comment: @guijob ? [`stateless`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_sem_estado) é justamente a "falta de sessão", acredito que o que este usuário busca é **"manter o estado"** e por isso busca por uma forma de manter dados em sessão!